# Let $A;B;C;D;E$ be real numbers such that $A$ is positive and $C$ is negative. The set of points (x; y) that satisfy $Ax^{2} + Bx ....

Tags: calculus, polynomials, conic-sections

Let $A;B;C;D;E$ be real numbers such that $A$ is positive and $C$ is negative. The set of points (x; y) that satisfy $Ax^{2} + Bx + Cy^{2} + Dy + E = 0 $ is (usually) a hyperbola.

a) Show this

b) Why "usually"? Can this set be something other than a hyperbola? (Hint: Complete the square; for example, if $A \neq 0$ write $Ax^{2} + Bx$ as $A(x + \frac{B}{2A})^{2}$ + a constant.

**Attempts:**

With regards to a) I think I may have indirectly worked through b). I didn't get a final solution nonetheless, but after working on a) and then glancing at b) this may have been the case. Anyways

a) this asks to show that the above expression is usually a hyperbola based on the given conditions. So to me that meant I had to try and put the equation into the following form"

$$\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}} - \frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}} = 1$$

As this isone of the general forms of the hyperbola. That being said I looked at the expression given and I actually completed the square with respects to $x$ but I also did it with respect to $y$. Here are the crucial steps, given that $C$ is supposed to be seen as negative I labelled it $-C$:

$$ Ax^{2} + Bx - Cy^{2} + Dy + E = 0 \\ (Ax^{2} + Bx) - (Cy^{2} + Dy) + E = 0  \\ \bigg(x + \frac{B}{2A}\bigg)^{2} - \frac{C}{A}y^{2} + \frac{D}{A}y + \frac{E}{A} = \frac{B^{2}}{4A^{2}} \\ \text{now completeing the square of the y term}:\\ \frac{A}{C}\bigg(x +\frac{B}{2A}\bigg)^{2} - \bigg(y - \frac{D}{2c}\bigg)^{2} = \frac{B^{2}}{4AC} - \frac{D^{2}}{4c^{2}} - \frac{E}{C} $$

And this is where I'm stuck. If I divide everything by the constant that is on the right side of the equation I'll at least have the $1$ on the right side, but the left side won't be exactly in the form that I'm attempting to arrive at.

Questions: Did I even do the right thing for 1) and how should I approach 2)?

Comment: The “usually” is really a matter of terminology. The equation could represent a pair of intersecting lines, but many consider that to be a degenerate hyperbola.

Comment: It looks like you’ve edited your question to match the suggested equation in the answer after that answer had been given. Retrospective edits like that are generally a bad thing since they make part or all of the answer nonsensical. Your edit also negates part of your own question: after this edit, your statement that “the left side won’t be exactly in the form that I’m attempting to arrive at” is no longer true. I’ve rolled back your edit so that the question is in the form in which it was answered.

Comment: This makes sense @amd, thanks for doing that. Just out of curiosity, how did you catch the edit? Since I could only assume thousands of edits occur daily.

Comment: While reading through the question and answer, some of the statements didn’t make sense to me. I saw that the question had been edited by you more recently than the answer was posted, so I looked at the question’s edit history by clicking on the “edited xxx hours ago” link at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you gave restricts the center of the hyperbola to the origin. It would be more correct to say that the (one of) the general equations is
$$\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2} - \frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2} =1$$ Dividing by the term on the right should be sufficient from there.

For part (b), as suggested by @John Omielan, notice that if the RHS is zero then the equation reduces to

$$\sqrt{\frac AC} \left(x + \frac{B}{2A}\right) = \pm \left(y -\frac{D}{2C} \right) $$
which is clearly not a hyperbola, but a set of two lines.

Comment: You say the equation given restricts the center of the hyperbola to the origin, but how can I see this in what I wrote? In the general equation I'm aware it means $h = 0$ and $k = 0$, but I don't see this.

Comment: In your equation, $h= - \frac{B}{2A}$ and $k=\frac{D}{2C}$, which means the center of the hyperbola lies at $(h,k)$ instead of the origin. It’s basic graph translation.

Comment: Oh....I see what you were getting at.